# COUNTIF Function, reset count if value equals a specific value

Tags: excel, vba, formula, countif, running-count

I need to list a running count in column A of each occurrence of the value "4A" in column B, but the count needs to reset to 0 if the value in column B equals "2B".

I have attached a sample of my workbook, column A shows how I need the count to operate. I am open to using VB or a formula.

[image]

Or in text format:

```
| A | B  |
+---+----+
| 0 | 2B |
|   | 3A |
| 1 | 4A |
|   | 4B |
|   | 4B |
| 2 | 4A |
|   | 4B |
| 3 | 4A |
|   | 9A |
| 0 | 2B |
|   | 3A |
| 1 | 4A |
|   | 4C |
| 2 | 4A |
|   | 9A |
| 0 | 2B |
|   | 3A |
| 1 | 4A |
|   | 9A |
| 0 | 2B |
|   | 3A |
| 1 | 4A |
|   | 4C |
|   | 9A |
|   | 9B |
|   | 9Z |
```

Comment: Is it necessary to hide repeating values, like you have done in the sample sheet?

Comment: Minus 1 for posting an image of sample data.

Comment: Added the text version, for those who find its absence problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

@Jeeped and @trincot proposed better non-array versions. I modified them slightly here:

@Jeeped's formula:

```
=IF(OR(B1={"2B","4A"}), COUNTIF(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(B$1:B1)/(B$1:B1="2B"), 1)):B1, "4A"),"")
```

After modification it uses `LARGE` function in the aggregate rather than `SMALL` and `""` instead of `TEXT(,)`.

---

@trincot's formula:

```
=IF(OR(B2={"2B","4A"}),(B2="4A")*(1+IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(MAX(G$1:OFFSET(G2,-1,0))+1,G$1:OFFSET(G2,-1,0))),0)),"")
```

Compared to original, it's been rearranged slightly 'IF-wise', I also replaced magic `9999` with `MAX([...]) + 1` and made it so that you can just paste it in 1st cell and drag down rather than have two separate formulas for first cell and the consecutive ones.

---

My original version:

I think it has the benefit of perhaps being the easiest to understand (? - I am obviously biased here so I might be wrong) and it's physically the shortest of all.

It has the obvious drawback of being an array-formula.

In cell "A1" you can write:

```
=IF(OR(B1="2B",B1="4A"),SUM((B$1:B1="4A")*(ROW(B$1:B1)>MAX(ROW(B$1:B1)*(B$1:B1="2B")))),"")
```

It's an array formula so you have to confirm it with ctrl + shift + enter.

Then you can drag it down.

Basically it counts number of occurrences of "4A" in a range extending from current row to the first provided that rows of counted "4A" are larger than that last row of "2B".

Comment: @Jeeped - forgive me asking in a different place (because of my reputation) - what is wrong with posting an image of sample data here? It takes nearly zero effort to reproduce a workable example in this case.

Comment: The best post I can point to is [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812). Beyond that, someone asking for help (and showing no original effort) should not be expecting multiple other users to retype their data just to help them.

Comment: Nice array formula btw; I had worked up a non-array with AGGREGATE performing the cyclic processing but yours is shorter (`=IF(OR(B1={"2B","4A"}), COUNTIF(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:1)/(B$1:B1="2B"), COUNTIF(B$1:B1, "2B"))):B1, "4A"), TEXT(,))`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with standard (non-array) formulas:

In A1 put:

```
=IF(B1="4A",1,0)
```

In A2 put:

```
=IF(B2="2B",IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9999,A$1:A1))>0,0,""),
            IF(B2="4A",1+INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9999,A$1:A1)),""))
```

Drag/copy A2 down to the remaining cells in the A column.

This will produce blanks where otherwise the same value would be displayed.

If repeating values don't need to be suppressed, then you can simplify the formula in A2 to:

```
=IF(B2="2B",0,IF(B2="4A",1+A1,A1))
```

... and copy it down.